# VBA Resume execution after error

Tags: vba, ms-access

Recently I had an issue. 
When access app looses it's internet connection (and it's connection to database obviously), 3146 Error arises. The task was implement error handling, recovery and continue program execution after internet connection reestablished.

I did a lot of reading on MSDN and here on Stackoverflow and did not manage to find a clear-cut solution that addresses the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution that is going for me.
Here is a brief algorithm outline:

```
Sub name_of_the_sub
   Dim ...... As ....
   Dim ...... As ....
   ...

Loop_Label:

   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

   {code that might throw an error}
   ...

   GoTo Loop_Label

ErrorHandler:
   {log your error}
   {wait for a some time}
   {connect to data base}
   Resume Loop_Label:

 End Sub
```

Comment: I'd implement a counter for X tries (so the loop is not infinite), or simply a msgbox that informs the user connection was lost and if wants to retry or exit (again, providing a break for the loop)